# Finding duplicates in different sheets or giving a message box if duplicate is found

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, messagebox

I have tried several options already but can't get what I want.
I have a workbook of 31 sheets and each sheet has a column where number entries are entered. There can be duplicates in one sheet but there shouldn't be duplicates among different sheets. How should I do it?

So far I have come up with another sheet which takes all the values from other 31 using IF and with the help of a macro button removes duplicates in each column (for each sheet). There is a conditional formatting on top so it shows in that sheet whether duplicate was entered or not. However, it would be best if there would be a popup saying there is a duplicate.

In the sheet with all the entries I also have 0 and Empty values which will be in every column in every case.

Best solution would be to have a button which can be pressed whenever the check is needed.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Did i forget to mention that I am a total noob in terms of VBA? I do not think things that I tried are relevant. As I only need the code for the button to be placed in each sheet "Check" which would check the sheet with all the values and give a message if a duplicate is found, except for 0 and Empty.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Update your question with the currently working  code/macro you mentioned so we know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need VBA. Even though I am a software developer I try to use as little VBA as I can.

Lets say your values of all 31 sheets are on every sheet in A1-A10. Then do the following per sheet:

First create a column with the unique values of the sheet. For that you need a "matrix formula". Skip C1 and type the following formula in cell C2 and close with CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER (not just ENTER!):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$10, MATCH(0, IF(ISBLANK($A$1:$A$10),1,COUNTIF($C$1:C1, $A$1:$A$10)), 0)),"")
```

Now you get a matrix formula. As you can see there are now brackets {} around the formula.
Now fill the formula down to C11 and you get only the unique values of A1-A10. After you did this 31 times, reference all 31 columns C to an overview sheet.

You can see the duplicates in the overview sheet with conditional formatting. It is explained [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/find-duplicates.html). With this solution it will be very easy to pinpoint the duplicates.

But if you want to have values instead of formatting, create a second overview sheet and put this formula in A1:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(OverviewSheet!A1),IF(OverviewSheet!A1<>0,COUNTIF(OverviewSheet!$A$1:$AE$10,OverviewSheet!A1)>1))
```

and fill this formula to cell AE10. You will get a whole range of TRUE/FALSE. This formula also takes empty cell and zeros into account.

Now place this formula somewhere on the second overview sheet:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:AE10,TRUE())>0
```

Now you have one cell that contains only TRUE or FALSE if you have duplicates over your 31 sheets.

If you want this result under a button I am convinced you will be able to create a macro for this.

Maybe there are shorter results, but this is what I came up with.

Success!

EDIT:

OK, maybe I was too positive about VBA. Let's say the last formula is in AF1, then this is your macro:

```
Sub Check()
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OverviewSheet2").Range("AF1").Value = True Then
        MsgBox "We have duplicates!"
    Else
        MsgBox "We have no duplicates."
    End If
End Sub
```

Now the most simple option for this macro is to put in under a shortcut-key (View -> Macros -> View Macros -> Select 'Check' macro -> Options... -> Shortcut key), e.g. CTRL-SHIFT-D. Then you don't need 31 buttons on every sheet.